# Did Devi Parvati ever worship Sri Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, parvati

I have read that Sri Vishnu worships Devi Parvati and Lord Shiva.

> Nama Shivaabhyam sarasothsavabhyam,
> Namaskruthabheeshta vara prathabhyam,
> Narayanenarchitha padukabhyam,
> Namo Nama Sankara Parvatheebhyam

Salutations to Lord Shiva and Goddess Shivaa,
Whose playful love is a festival,
Who grant boons to those who salute them,
And whose feet is worshipped by Lord Narayana,
Salutations and salutations to Lord Sankara
And to that Goddess Parvathy.
-Uma Maheshwar Stotram

But did Devi Parvati worship Sri Vishnu? Which Purana mentions this?

Comment: please provide verse sources for the question if possible. It may help to get a quicker/better answer.